# How can I disable new mail icon in one specific email account in Microsoft Office 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I have 3 email accounts.

One of them is not really important for me, but unfortunately I need it, because this is my business email address, and sometimes my boss asks me search for something in the account.

However, I don't need notifications for from new emails from this account.

I have set the desktop notification, and sounds, now the only thing I still want to change is the new mail envelope on the icon:

[image: Remove new mail icon from taskbar]

What can I do so this icons doesn't appear for email to business account?
(the other accounts need it!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### How do I disable the New Mail Desktop Alert for specific accounts?

> There is not a direct setting for this in Outlook, but you can achieve
>   this by disabling the generic option to display the New Mail Desktop
>   Alert and then create a rule to display it again when mail arrives via
>   your specified account(s).
>
> **Disabling New Mail Desktop Alert**
>
> As said, the first step of the process is to disable the generic
>   option to always display the New Mail Desktop Alert.
>
> - Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007
>
>   Tools-> Options…-> button: E-mail Options…-> button: Advanced E-mail Options…-> option: Display a New Mail Desktop Alert
> - Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013
>
>   File-> Options-> Mail-> section: Message arrival-> option: Display a Desktop Alert
> - Uncheck Display a Desktop Alert
>
> [image]
>
> **Creating a New Mail Desktop Alert rule for specific accounts**
>
> The next step is to create a rule to display the New Mail Desktop
>   Alert again but only for the accounts that you select.
>
> The approach is slightly different for when you want to disable alerts
>   for only 1 account or multiple.
>
> **Disable alert for 1 specific account**
>
> When you have multiple accounts configured and only want to disable
>   the alerts for 1 specific account, then you need to create the
>   following rule:
>
> 1. Open the Rules and Alerts dialog;
>
>    - Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007
>
>      Tools-> Rules and Alerts… (press OK if you get an HTTP warning)
>    - Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2013
>
>      File->  button: Manage Rules & Alerts
> 2. When you see the “Apply changes to this folder” drop down list at the top, make sure that the account which you want to exclude is
>      selected here.
>
>    [image]
>
>    3. Button New Rule…
>    4. Select “Start from a blank rule” and verify that “Check messages when they arrive” or “Apply rule on message I receive” is selected.
>    5. Press Next to go to the Conditions screen.
>    6. Verify that no condition is selected and press Next.
>    7. A warning will pop-up stating that this rule will apply to all messages. Press “Yes” to indicate that that is correct.
>    8. Select the action “display a Desktop Alert”.
>    9. Press Next.
>    10. Select: except through the specified account
>    11. At the bottom, click on “specified” and then select the account for which you want to see the alert.
>    12. Press Finish to complete the rule.
>
> The entire rule will now read as follows:
>
> ```
> Apply this rule after the message arrives
> on this computer only
> display a Desktop Alert
> except through the <account name> account
> ```
>
> For the other email accounts which still need alerts:
>
> - Repeat steps 1 to 12 **except for 10 and 11** When you had the “Apply changes to this folder” drop down list as mentioned in step 2,
>     you’ll need to repeat the above steps for all the other accounts
>     listed but you can then skip step 10 and 11.
>
>   If you do not do this, you won’t see alerts for these accounts.

Source [Disable New Mail Desktop Alert for specific accounts](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/disable-new-mail-alert-for-specific-accounts)

---

#### How do I show/hide the new mail envelope?

> Outlook 2010
>
> When you are using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7, then the new mail envelope will no longer be displayed in the Notification Area.
>
> Instead, the icon of Outlook on the Taskbar will actually change to
>   inform you about a new message.
>
> Unfortunately, when you’ve set your Taskbar in Windows 7 to use small
>   icons, you will not get an envelope notification at all.
>
> In that case you could consider reconfiguring the New Mail Desktop
>   Alert to be displayed as a permanent notification.
>
> Note 1:
>
> The new mail envelope is only being displayed for messages delivered
>   to the (default) Inbox. For additional accounts you can use a New Mail
>   Desktop Alert.
>
> Note 2:
>
> The option to show/hide the new mail envelope for Outlook can be found
>   in;
>
> - Outlook 2007 and previous
>
>   Tools-> Options…-> tab Preferences-> button E-mail Options…-> button Advanced E-mail Options…-> option: Show an envelope in the
>     notification area
> - Outlook 2010
>
>   File-> section Options-> section Mail-> option group Message arrival-> option: Show an envelope in the taskbar

Source [New mail envelope and Windows 7](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/398)

Comment: This not was what I need.
This thing only remove blue notification box, I need remove new mail icon from taskbar, like the picture is showed:
http://i59.tinypic.com/sy83me.png

Comment: @HerbáriaBalance Answer updated. Please read the second part.

Comment: Okey, but this remove messange icon for all accounts, and this is not good.
Like I saied in the question, only one case no need for this icon.
In other accounts need it, and I dosen't see any specifick rule for this.

Comment: @HerbáriaBalance "The new mail envelope is only displayed for messages delivered to the (default) Inbox". You can change your default Inbox **but** you will have to choose which of your other accounts gets the new mail envelope. You cannot have it for **both** of your other accounts.

Comment: Okey, thank you, so the answer is that's not possible at all.
You answer is correct, so I can accept that, even if I no find solution for this.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: If other users are using the same account that I want to disable notifications for myself, how can I enable this rule only for my PC? Tnx.